# Store function return value or use it immediately c++

Tags: c++

Consider the following code

```
#include <iostream>

int get_value();

int main() {
    //METHOD 1
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        std::cout << get_value() << std::endl;
    }

    //METHOD 2
    int the_value = get_value();
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        std::cout << the_value << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}

int get_value() {
    return 5;
}
```

Whenever I read code online most people seem to be using method 1. That is calling the get_value function several times even though it will return the same value each time. Would it not be alot more efficient to store the variable in the_value as shown in method 2? Or am I missing some benefit of using method 1?

Comment: What does get_value() do? You are right in general, but often it's so fast to recompute it that it doesn't matter.

Comment: Method 2 will print the same value over and over again. Method one could print different values if `get_value` returns different things.

Comment: This really depends on your actual situation.  If `get_value()` can change, then calling it in the loop is what you want. If it can't, then calling once is what you want.  Do note that a decent compiler could optimize the function call out of the loop if it knows it will always get the same value.  You'd have to profile or look at the assembly to see if it makes a difference.

Answer (score 1):

If get_value() always return the same thing, make a simple assignment before the loop.

For example, you can make the get_value() constexpr (but YMMV in your actual work context)

```
constexpr int get_value() {
    return 5;
}

int main()
{
    constexpr int the_value = get_value();
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        std::cout << the_value << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: If it's `constexpr`, I'd say it doesn't matter if you call it in the loop or not.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Remember, `constexpr` doesn't guarantee compile time evaluation, it only allows for it.  The compiler could decide to still call the function at run time.

Answer (score 1):

The answer as to which is the better way depends entirely on the definition of get_value().

If it is indeed a constant return value, and you didn't just simplify it for the question, then call it once, store the value, and use it during your loop.

It will be way more efficient if the compiler doesn't optimize the call away, and makes no difference if the compiler does. There's no downside unless your memory is so tight that saving that extra variable matters. Of course, this also means there's a design weakness ... why are we calling a function when a constant would do just as well?

HOWEVER ... if get_value() is not a constant, you need to call it on every iteration in case it changed.